# SQLite insert upon page refresh

Tags: php, mysql

I have few input types on a form and a submit button as following:

```
<form id="register_form" method="post" role="form" action="">
    <input autofocus="" id="firstname" name"firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required />
    <textarea id="Address" name="Adress" placeholder="No Address" type="text" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
    <select id="country" name="country" required>
            <option selected>Choose</option>
            <option value="10">Germany</option>
            <option value="11">Poland</option>
            <option value="12">United Kingdom</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit My New Entry</button>
</form>
```

Also i have a PHP code for submitting my data to a SQLite database:

```
<?php
try {
    //open the database
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:db/users.db');

    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"]; 
    $Address = $_POST["Address"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    
    //Insert record  
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO details 
                        (firstname, Address, country) 
                VALUES ('$firstname', '$Address', '$country')");

    $db = NULL;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    print 'Exception : ' .$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

My problem is that every time i refresh the page the script cause to register a new entry into my databse with empty fields, even if some input fields are marked as required or the databse table is set to rollback on NULL value (both are ignored).
How can i avoid this?

PS. required works only if i press the submit button.

Comment: Is it true that the PHP script also contains the HTML form ? (because the form action="")

Comment: they both are in the same "register.php" file

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP script contains both the PHP and HTML (the form), so if you load this script, the PHP script will be triggered immediately, which will insert a blank record

(1) So, you should slightly amend the page so that only if there is form submission by POST (when someone submits the form), then to do the PHP part, by adding say :

```
if (isset($_POST["firstname"])){
// the PHP codes
}
```

(2) There is a typo in your HTML form, name="Adress" should be name="Address"

(3) Please use parameterized prepared statement in your PHP insert query to avoid SQL injection attacks

So the code is:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["firstname"])){

try {
    //open the database
    $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:db/users.db');

    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"]; 
    $Address = $_POST["Address"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    
$data = [
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'Address' => $Adddress,
    'country' => $country,
];

$sql="INSERT INTO details (firstname, Address, country) VALUES (:firstname, :Address, :country)";

$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);

$pdo = NULL;
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    print 'Exception : ' .$e->getMessage();
}}
?>

<form id="register_form" method="post" role="form" action="#">
<table border=0><tr><td>
First Name: 
<td>
<input autofocus="" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" required />
<tr><td>
Address: 
<td><textarea id="Address" name="Address" placeholder="No Address" type="text" rows="3" cols="30"></textarea>
<tr><td>
Country: <td>
<select id="country" name="country" required>
            <option selected>Choose</option>
            <option value="10">Germany</option>
            <option value="11">Poland</option>
            <option value="12">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
<tr><td><button type="submit">Submit My New Entry</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to block the code from running.

This code, checks for the POST data and checks so there is content.
Then runs the database processing.

PHP

```
<?php
function processData()
{
  try
  {
    list($firstname, $address, $country) = $_POST;
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:db/users.db');
    $db->prepare("INSERT INTO details (firstname, address, country) VALUES (:firstname, :address, :country)");
    $db->bindValue(":address", $address, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $db->bindValue(":country", $country, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $db->bindValue(":firstname", $firstname, SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $db->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $e)
  {
    printf("Exception : %s", $e->getMessage());
  }
}
if (
  (isset($_POST["firstname"]) && !empty($_POST["firstname"]))
  && (isset($_POST["address"]) && !empty($_POST["address"]))
  && (isset($_POST["country"]) && !empty($_POST["country"]))
)
{
  processData();
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form
  action=""
  id="register_form"
  method="post"
  role="form"
>
  <input
    autofocus
    id="firstname"
    name"firstname"
    placeholder="First Name"
    type="text"
    required
  />
  <textarea
    id="address"
    name="address"
    placeholder="No address"
    type="text"
    rows="3"
    cols="30"
  ></textarea>
  <select
    id="country"
    name="country"
    required
  >
    <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
    <option value="10">Germany</option>
    <option value="11">Poland</option>
    <option value="12">United Kingdom</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit My New Entry</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Downvoted because this answer includes SQL injection. Please provide an answer that adheres to security standards to help others write safer code.

Comment: @MaartenDev for you, I've added SQL Injection, prevention.